How do I pass multiple Task Flow outputs from a single task to two Task Flow tasks downstream with a ShortCircuitOperator between them
I am trying to use a ShortCircuitOperator as a check point between an initial task and 2 tasks downstream that run in parallel. I am running on Airflow 2.0.2. The issue I run into is that the ShortCircuitOperator is always either being run in parallel with the final 2 tasks, or the final 2 tasks are run both in parallel with the ShortCircuitOperator AND downstream from the ShortCircuitOperator. Additionally, the 2 tasks downstream and the ShortCircuitOperator run with output form the initial task.
I have been trying to set dependencies in a variety of ways as part of an iteration for 2 unique ids
   for id in ids:
        get_table_data = get_data(Id)
        table_evaluation = ShortCircuitOperator(
            task_id=f'table_evaluation_{Id}',
            python_callable=evaluation,
            op_args=[get_table_data["table_eval"]]
        )
        mapping_table_build = build_mapping_tables(get_table_data["ext"],get_table_data["name"])
        survey_table_build =     update_survey_tables(get_table_data["ext"],get_table_data["name"],get_table_data["Token"])
        get_table_data >> table_evaluation >> [mapping_table_build,survey_table_build]

Gives me both the table_evaluation,mapping_table_build, and survey_table_build in parallel as well as  [mapping_table_build,survey_table_build] downstream from table_evaluation.
If I just allow the taskflow to set dependencies
   for id in ids:
        get_table_data = get_data(Id)
        table_evaluation = ShortCircuitOperator(
            task_id=f'table_evaluation_{Id}',
            python_callable=evaluation,
            op_args=[get_table_data["table_eval"]]
        )
        build_mapping_tables(get_table_data["ext"],get_table_data["name"])
        update_survey_tables(get_table_data["ext"],get_table_data["name"],get_table_data["Token"])

then all three (table_evaluation,build_mapping_tables, and update_survey_tables) are only in parallel downstream from get_table_data.
Even if I try and pass an output from table_evaluation to both build_mapping_tables and update_survey_tables, I receive the tasks in both parallel and downstream
